# Android preprocessing webview which has MathJax

Tags: android, mathjax

I am developing a education android application which basically allows users to watch a course video and then do a little quiz attached to that video. The activity to display videos is like this:

[image: video screen]

The activity contains a viewpager and a tabhost because there may be more than 1 videos for this topic. If I click the button located at bottom-left, I will go to the quiz activity which is like this:

[image: quiz screen]

The quiz activity also has a viewpager and a tabhost, because it has more than one question. Each question fragment is a listview with 5 items, each of them is a webview.

Because the course materials cover some science topics, in the quiz I have to use webview and MathJax to display mathematical formulae and equations.

The problem is, when I enter the quiz activity, it takes a very long time, usually more than 10 seconds, to render the LaTex. This is too long. We actually did some tricks to the iOS app to solve this problem, which is that we load the quiz view when user is watching the video. The quiz view shares the same controller with the video view, and when it is loading, it is outside the screen which make it invisible. When user clicks the quiz button, we just reposition the screen so that the quiz view is in the screen. Is there any work around like this in Android? I really appreciate any help from you. Thank you!